# Troubleshoot poor upload performance with Power BI Report Server

Tags: power-bi-report-server

I am suffering from very slow and unreliable performance uploading reports from Power BI Desktop to the Power BI Report Server. This is a long-standing issue on our system which seems to have become worse with our update to the January 2022 version of PBIRS.

When attempting to save within PowerBI RS I consistently get this aggravating error message: "Saving to Power BI Report Server was cancelled by the user."
[image: "Saving to Power BI Report Server was cancelled by the user."]

(I certainly did *not* cancel anything!!!)

The usual suggested workaround is to save the report to my Windows desktop and then manually upload to the report server, in which case I get the "loading" message for several minutes: "Please wait..."
[image: "Please wait..."]

Followed by a more descriptive error: "An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database."
[image: "An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database."]

This happens for relatively small reports -- one is only 38MB in size and still suffers this issue.

We are on a reliable coporate network and I can consistently ping the server with a 25ms response time.

The issue is intermittent - occasionally an upload will succeed, although recently the failure rate is over 80%.

The Power BI server itself has plenty of memory and disk space and appears to exceeds all the published hardware requirements for PBIRS. As previously mentioned, we have just updated to the latest version (January 2022, 15.0.1108.153).

So that's the situation.

I am wondering if anyone has ideas on what is happening here, and how to troubleshoot... (Is there a configurable timeout value for uploads which we could extend?)

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with this problem when users used machines with slow network connection. Workaround is to save pbix file locally and then to use Upload button directly from PBIRS portal.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue with big files (1.4gb). We changed the setting to accept 2GB files but it didnt work either.

Interestingly it worked on our INT environment. So we analyzed the setting and found out that the log file on the PROD DB was set to 4GB and during upload it hit this threshold. On INT it was had UNLIMITED size. So we changed that on PROD and it worked.

```
ALTER DATABASE [REPORT_SERVER_DBNAME] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = 'REPORT_SERVER_DBNAME_log', MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
```